One way function bulit by singular matrices
Our one-way function $F:\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ differs from traditional OWFs, which focus on being hard to invert. Instead, ours aims to be difficult to determine which preimage is correct. Such a one-way function can be constructed as follows.

$C=A\times B$, where $B\in\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ is a singular square matrix, $Rank(B)=n/2$, $A\in \mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ is a full rank matrix, $q$ is a prime.

Given matrices $C$ and $B$, is it hard to recover the matrix $A$ or patrial entries of $A$?
Formally, $\text{Pr}[info(A):B\in \mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n},Rank(B)<n,C=A\times B]\leq \epsilon$, where $info(A)$ denotes any information about $A$.

An example over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $q=65537,n=4$.
The singular matrix $B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}45486&33969&47434&1129\\50585&30352&54018&33044\\18346&16233&7013&13403\\12177&36523&16428&26582\end{array}\right)$.
The result $\left.C=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}9605&8658&35595&34119\\59342&35066&46074&35682\\57149&58797&40560&62867\\6125&9457&30785&58689\end{array}\right.\right)$.

Is there any efficient method to recover the correct matrix $A$? or partial entries in $A$?

The matrix $\left.A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}26903&56799&35632&41350\\49093&15412&25540&13964\\14708&23535&3827&63911\\56190&32614&6340&41196\end{array}\right.\right)$


Are you looking for the specific entries in the $A$ that was actually used?  Or, any $A$ that satisfies the $C = A \times B$ equation?

@poncho Yes, as you mentioned, I am interested in finding specific entries in matrix $A$, even when the rank of matrix $B$ is $n-1$. Intuitively, if the rank of matrix $B$ is less than its order, there will be multiple possible matrices A that satisfy this condition.
